# Calculating a due date based off date created and priority excluding weekends

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I want to create a due date column (calculated column) that is auto-populated using the date created and priority column, while excluding weekends. In my priority column I have the following options: Critical, High & Standard.

- Critical = 1 day
- High = 5 days
- Standard = 10 days

Based off what date the item was created and the priority selected, I want the due date to auto-populate whilst excluding weekends. I really don't know anything about putting formulas together and would really appreciate a drafted formula for the above.

EDIT - I had a go at building this formula myself however I have a syntax error and wondering if it has something to do with spaces, as I currently do not have any spaces in my formula. Also not even sure the formula is correct.

=[Created]+IF(Priority="Critical",1, IF(WEEKDAY([Created])>5,[Created]+3,IF(WEEKDAY([Created])>1,[Created]+1,IF[Created]+IF(Priority="High",5,IF(WEEKDAY([Created])>5,[Created]+10,IF(WEEKDAY([Created])>1,[Created]+8+IF[Created]+IF(Priority="Standard",10,IF(WEEKDAY([Created])>5,[Created]+17,IF(WEEKDAY([Created])>1,[Created]+15

Any help on this would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch of brackets in your formula, can you share with me the logic of your formula? I'm a bit confused about it.